# Use typewriter package with fontspec

Tags: luatex, fontspec

I would like to use the `typewriter` package along with another font. I tried to do that with the `fontspec` package. I wouldn't mind to use the Latin Modern  font.  However, the style of the font remains in the `typewriter` package, which I only would like to use in certain cases in the document. Is there a way to do that?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\providecommand\ttgreyone{0.4}
\providecommand\ttgreytwo{0.5}
\providecommand\ttrotatebold{12}
\providecommand\ttdownbold{20000}
\providecommand\ttrightbold{35000}
\providecommand\ttdownshifttwo{20000}

\providecommand\ttrotatenormal{8}
\providecommand\ttrightnormal{20000}
\providecommand\ttdownnormal{20000}

\usepackage{typewriter}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}     

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]    
\end{document}
```

Comment: the package was not really set up for this, it might take a few changes (ie copy typewriter.sty and adjust.... getting the main document fonts back is probably easy, but math mode is more or less destroyed by the package so you'd need to move those definitions into a new mathversion and just switch mathversion when you switch to typewriter mode. Sorry I have no time in next few days but maybe this comment gives someone a hint to answer.

Answer (score 6):

A bit of a place-holder answer.

The font is hard-coded in.

A very quick hack, to turn it into a parameter. Without a `fontspec` interface.

In the main tex file, do:

```
\newcommand\xattfname{PT Serif} 
\usepackage{typewriter2a}
```

And three changes to make in a modified/renamed `typewriter2a.sty` (save it in the same location as the main file). The commented-out line is the original.

```
%\font\cmuntt = file:cmuntt.otf at 12pt \cmuntt

\font\cmuntt = "\xattfname "  at 12pt \cmuntt
```

and

```
%              f.name = 'cmtt10x'
                    f.name = '\xattfname '
```

and

```
%              f.fonts = {{ name = 'file:cmuntt', size = size}}
              f.fonts = {{ name = '\xattfname ', size = size}}
```

Then back in the main file, do:

```
\fontname\font
\lipsum[1-2]
```

so the fontname prints in the output.

I used 14pt:

[image: Tinos]

[image: PT Serif]

[image: Raleway]

Doesn't work for all fonts (just NFSS ones?).

The randomness might need tweaking, perhaps. It might be a bit hard to read lengthy blocks of such text.

Close-up of Linux Libertine G:

[image: Linux Libertine G]

Overall effect: endearingly cute!

And a cup of something for the thesis reader! :)

Comment: Hm... I think what OP wants is not change the font of the package to something else, but to limit the scope of the package. Something like `\typewriterON`...`\typewriterOFF`.

Comment: Nice answer, +1. I think @PhelypeOleinik is right though, that the OP also would like to switch the typewriter effect on and off, which would require (probably a lot) more changes in the code.