# How to use the typewriter package "locally"?

Tags: fonts, typewriter

Is there a way to enclose the effects of the typewriter package locally, into an environment for example as suggested by [Phelype Oleinik's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490025/use-typewriter-package-with-fontspec/490984#comment1239709_490984) in a [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/490984/262081) (with something like `\begin{typewriter}...\end{typewriter}`)?

David Carlisle has suggested some ideas in [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490025/use-typewriter-package-with-fontspec#comment1237390_490025) but that's way beyond my skills...

Here a non Working Minimal Exemple if needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{typewriter}
\usepackage{verbatim}% For presentation purposes only.

\begin{document}

Some text with normal font, i.e. "typewriter mode" disabled (doesn't work in this example).
Some Math $ \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2} $ 

\verb!\begin{typewriter}!

Some text with the "typewriter mode" enabled.
Some Math $ \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2} $

\verb!\end{typewriter}!

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you consider that this question is a duplicate of the [related one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/490025/262081) than you can directly answer the related question (which has no accepted answer yet) and I will delete this one. Please just tell me what would be the best conduct.

Comment: the version at https://github.com/davidcarlisle/dpctex/tree/main/typewriter has a few more features than the version on ctan, I suppose I should make the settings local it was just writen as a joke originally so doesn't have much structure. If you add an issue at that githup repo I may get to it (but not for a while)

Comment: @David Carlisle Do the new features make it easier to achieve local formatting? I didn't find the answer in the github repo... Anyway, thank you very much for your reactivity and your nice joke-package!

Comment: @David Carlisle Is it easy to change the color in the source code? For exemple to use red color as default color instead of black. I didin't find how to do it...

Comment: it doesn't do anything about color, does `\color{red}`  not work? (using color or xcolor packages as normal?

Comment: @David Carlisle I can't get any color with `\color` or `\textcolor` with `xcolor` package, everything is black... But It's a good news if it should works. Thanks again for your reactivity!

Comment: "should work" is putting it strongly I don't think I actively stopped it working but it's not as if I tested it with color

Comment: @David Carlisle Could you consider testing it quickly on your end, if that's not too much to ask?

Comment: perhaps later, can't now.

Comment: @David Carlisle I post [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/636231/262081) to deal with my color problem only. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle hm, things like `special','pdf: ' .. string.format("\%f",greybolda) .. ' g'`  looks very much like actively stopping color ;-)

Comment: I blame @UlrikeFischer

Comment: @UlrikeFisher I don't understand a thing about this code. Nevertheless, I thought I understood that it is the `g` which gives the gray color... If yes, how can I change this color with a macro which could be changed at the beginning (as it is done for example with some parameters, eg: `\providecommand\ttgreyone{..}`)

Comment: you can't. It would be possible to change the grayness but you can't change to a rgb or cmyk color, @DavidCarlisle would imho have to adapt the code here.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I did have a quick look of changing `greynormala g` to `greynormala * 1 .. ' ' .. greynormala * 0.5 .. ' ' greynormala * 0.1 .. 'rg'` to get some shade of 1 0.5 .1 rg  but it made some legal pdf that's all black:-) I may look again later...