# How to change text color with typewriter package?

Tags: fonts, color, typewriter

How to change the text color with the `typewriter` package?

Currently, with this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{typewriter}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\color{red}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{blue}{a  rule:} \rule{3cm}{1pt}
display math:
\[\left(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+y}}\right)\]

\end{document}
```

I get this result:

[image]

Where there are only the rules in red...

**Am I doing something wrong?**

*BTW the rule are not printed with several hyphens (------) as shown in the documentation...*

Comment: @DavidCarlisle
 would know for sure, but I don't think that (much like the old typewriter this package is emulating) color is an option in this context …

Comment: @Ingmar I'm touched by your faith in my ability to know what my code does: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636121/how-to-use-the-typewriter-package-locally?noredirect=1#comment1585583_636121

Comment: @Ingmar I should use the `inkpadcolor` package ;)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you'll curse me but it seems that one can't change the document font size either (e.g. 12pt) and also can't use commands such as `\large`, `\tiny`, etc...

Comment: @SylvainRigal it's a major job to change the hammers on a typewriter to a larger size, it tends to jam the mechanism. the ctan version does have `\providecommand\ttbasefont{cmuntt.otf}\providecommand\ttfontsize{12pt}` so you can have any font and any size you want by setting those, but font sizes changes are then ignored.
`